# Pulling images from the media folder category to display inside a page

Tags: pages, media-library

I'm looking to pull images from the media library by a certain category. The images are uploaded by the client themselves via the Media menu in the admin panel and they also select the category. The images located in that category should then automatically display in the home page in 6 columns across the page, limited to 18 at a time.

Have installed and tested various media gallery plugins and used the WP Bakery 'Media gallery' and 'Post' elements but the issue is that they do not have a setting to update the gallery each time a new image is added in the media folder and attached to a certain category, and there is no way of limiting the number of images to display. So it appears to me that this can only be achieved by customization.

Hope this make sense...

Comment: Image category? Post category? Are images standalone, attachments or featured? Category page? Dedicated page? Please fix your question.

Comment: Uploaded using FTP? Please fix your question, don't comment!